# AAPT Crashes after added Facebook sdk 3.0 as Library

Tags: android, facebook

i am upgrading Facebook SDK with my application, after added the Facebook SDK 3.0 as library in my application, eclipse trying to build my app then aapt is crashed. here below the only log information which i am getting for this issue

Error executing aapt: Return code -1073741819

its kind of weird, don't have an clue of what and where its going wrong. i guess some problem with resources, seems like its getting conflict with my project resources.

Note: if i add the Facebook sdk 2.0 its working fine

Expecting some help or approach to resolve this issue

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After day of painful search, i have resolved the problem,in my project style.xml for some of the styles definitions have android:id , this causes the aapt crash, after i removed this its working fine.